# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity authorization or authentification with razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I try to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity with pages. Can I do it or I must choose Razor Pages authorization conventions like in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/razor-pages-authorization? I `see

```
services.AddMvc()


  .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Account/Manage");
    options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Account/Logout");
});`
```

I have .cshtml file with

```
  @model Proj_s.Models.AccountViewModels.RegisterViewModel
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Register";
    }
    <h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>
    .......
    @section Scripts {
        @await Html.PartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial")
    }
```

I replace 
    `@page @model Proj_s.Pages.Projects.DetailsModel`with
    `@model Proj_s.Models.AccountViewModels.RegisterViewModel`

What the best way to add authentification or authorization to existing razor page that does not contain this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ASP.NET Core Identity and Razor Pages. Check [this article](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/312/introduction-to-identity-in-razor-pages)

In general, just create a template and see how this is implemented.

```
dotnet new razor --auth individual
```

Be aware though, that Razor Pages are a little tricky when it comes to customization.

Comment: Do you prefer MVC? I found consisten MVC tutorial on ASP.NET Core Identity

Comment: In article you gave me author create new razor project with authorization. But I wanna [b]add[/b] it. Ok, I would try borrow code from new razor project and add it to my wy existing

Comment: Do you have Razor pages (Foo.cshtml.cs) or Classic MVC (Controller, Razor View) in your project? It's hard to help you unless you provide more details on what you have and what is your goal.

Comment: I have razor pages. I wanna add new  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity  registration. Of course it would bee good idea to add some MVC controllers but there is conflict between views in razor and MVC..

Comment: What do you mean by conflict between views and MVC? Razor Pages and Controllers/Views approach are parts of MVC. And you can have Razor Pages and Controllers at a same time in your project. E.g. the template that you get with "dotnet new razor --auth individual" has both pages and AccountController.

Comment: Ok I should create new post.

Answer (score 0):

Most common and widely accepted practice is it use `[Authorize]` attribute.

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
    }

    public ActionResult Logout()
    {
    }
}
```

This is how you protect your view. `[Authorize]` checks if the user is logged in or not and sends them back to the configured page (login) if they aren't. You can also check if the logged in user is in role like this `[Authorize("RoleName")]`

[More details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple)

Comment: But what if I do have not controllers on razor? I do not use MVC but wanna use it.

Comment: I do not use simple authorization